# Does Outlook's 'Clean Up Folder' delete 2 copies of the same email, 1 with attachment and 1 without?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I don't know if [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-conversation-clean-up-to-delete-redundant-messages-HA102749184.aspx) relates to emails with attachments.

Suppose I send an email with an attachment in April, and then resend the same email WITHOUT the attachment in May. Would 'Clean Up Folder' delete the April email?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use the clean up feature in outlook 2013, and it appears to me that emails that had attachments and were not the newest email in the chain, were LEFT in my folder and not deleted.

Hope that helps.